# Como buscar tags usando Expressão Regular?

Tags: c#, regex

Gostaria de criar uma expressão regular que busque as tags:

```
<b>, <p>, <i>
```

Como faria isso em expressão regular?

Comment: Tavez possa lhe [ajudar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298353/how-can-i-extract-a-string-between-strong-tags-usings-c)!

Comment: Você quer buscar para que? pegar o que tem entre elas? apagar?

Comment: na realidade apagar @JuniorNunes

Comment: apagar tudo dentro da tag ou só as tags?

Comment: Buscar em um texto por exemplo o usuário digitou <i>olá<i/> eu quero localizar e remover as tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a expressão `@"\<([\/?\s?\w]+)\>`

Veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("<p> olá </ br>  nova linha </p>",  @"\<([\/?\s?\w]+)\>"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2flyzC

Você pode fazer o `Replace` direto com o `Regex`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string texto = "<p> olá </ br>  nova linha </p>";

        var match = Regex.Replace(texto,  @"\<([\/?\s?\w]+)\>", "");            

        Console.WriteLine(match);

    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NO2Jc4